# get last item that is not null in each

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var itemLength= $('.item').length;

        $.each(JSON.parse(json), function(idx, obj) {

            var itemId= obj.itemId;

                if(itemId!= null){

                    var temp = '<div id="'+ itemId +'"></div>'
                    $(temp).appendTo($('#somewhere'));

                }            

        });
```

how to prevent the last itemId to be appended? idx is not equal to item's length?

Comment: Side note: `appendTo` accepts a selector, no need for the `$()` around `#somewhere`. Though I'd probably do `$("#somewhere").append(temp)` instead.

Comment: Still a typo in question: `'<div id="'+ itemId +'"</div>'`??? Should be `'<div id="'+ itemId +'"></div>'`

Comment: @A.Wolff now it's ok?

Comment: so many downvote, where is the answer?

Comment: *"idx is not equal to item's length?"* You're not using `idx` or `itemLength` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to prevent the last itemId to be appended? idx is not equal to item's length?

That's one of the two straight-forward ways, yes, which are that and `slice`:

Doing the index thing is a bit easier if you use `forEach` instead of `$.each` (I'm assuming the JSON defines an array) because it gives you a reference to the array:

```
JSON.parse(json).forEach(function(obj, idx, array) {
    if (idx < array.length - 1 && obj) {
        if (obj.itemId) {
            $('#somewhere').append('<div id="' + obj.itemId + '"></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

But if you prefer `$.each`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
    if (idx < data.length - 1 && obj) {
        if (obj.itemId) {
            $('#somewhere').append('<div id="' + obj.itemId + '"></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

Alternately, you could use `slice`:

```
JSON.parse(json).slice(0, -1).forEach(function(obj) {
    if (obj && obj.itemId) {
        $('#somewhere').append('<div id="' + obj.itemId + '"></div>');
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(json).slice(0, -1), function(idx, obj) {
    if (obj && obj.itemId) {
        $('#somewhere').append('<div id="' + obj.itemId + '"></div>');
    }
});
```

(When you give `slice` a negative index, it's treated as an offset from the end.)

---

No matter what you use, I'd probably lookup `#something` **once** and reuse the resulting jQuery object.